# How can I get the data from a .wav file into an array or list to plot?

Tags: python-2.7, fft, wav

I am trying to get the data from a .wav file to perform a FFT and then use that to find out the freq of the note played. I found out how to open the file, but I can't figure out from the online documentation how to get the data into an array or list to perform operations on it. Below is the code I have written so far.

```
import wave
harp=wave.open('/Users/williamweiss2/Desktop/Test 2/harp.wav','r')
print("Frame rate of Harp sample is",harp.getframerate())
print(harp) #I thought that opening the file would automatically make an array.
```

Thanks so much for your suggestions.

Comment: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.io.wavfile.read.html

Comment: Note than an FFT alone is not a reliable function for determining the pitch frequency of a played musical note.  Pitch is psychoacoustic, and thus can be very different from spectrum frequency.  Perhaps try a pitch estimation algorithm, using weighted autocorrelation, ASDF or AMDF.

Comment: @hotpaw2 Thank you for that. I am doing this for a class and in the last assignment we transformed a .txt file's contents using the FFT and then knowing the sampling rate, number of samples and the change in freq between harmonies we estimated the pitch. I am trying to do the same here. I know I can get the number of samples in the recording and the sampling rate, but I am struggling isolating the data in a form that I can can them FFT it and plot the coefficients. Do you think I am on the right track?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Thanks for the link. That is how I eventually got it to work. I would choose your answer if it wasn't a comment. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You can get it as a string of bytes by using `harp.readframes(harp.getnframes())`.

Or you could store each frame as an element of a `list` as:

```
n=harp.getnframes()
l=[]
for i in range(n):
    l.append(harp.readframes(1))
```

Comment: `readframes(n)` where `n` is the number of frames you want to read.

Comment: Also, I copied what you did and then tried to plot it. I do not think I am understanding what is really happening.  I got this error. "could not convert string to float: U�� " Any ideas why that would happen? Thanks again.